# Swipebox incompatibility with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, video, plugins, conflict

I have created a static video gallery which links up thumbnail images to a lightbox jQuery plugin (Swipebox). It works beautifully across all devices. My issue is now I have started to streamline the data into an AngularJS structure, it has stopped working.

I have used the ng-repeat directive to call the specific thumbnails, captions and video URL's for each project in a `$scope.projects[]` array, and now it loads the lightbox window but fails to actually link to the video URL.

If anybody has come across a solution for this, or can speculate what might be wrong I would be very appreciative. I've spent a long time trying to figure out what is causing it, to no avail.

Failing that, any other good video lightbox plugins?

Comment: URL for working static site: http://documentalfilms.co.uk/

URL for broken Angular site: http://testingtesting123.info/

Comment: Could you provide any code? Swipebox can work perfectly until you need to call specific functions on the currently open video/image. Otherwise, it works fine with Angular.js